# Get date from HTML datepicker and send to JS script

Tags: javascript, php, html, datepicker

I want to send the date and time set in an HTML form to a js script (different page). However, I'm a noob and don't know how xD
What I've tried so far is sending the date and time (from two inputs) to the same page, triggering PHP code, setting a cookie containing the two values (this works).

How would I get this data and set it into a js function?

Is the date and time even in the correct format? if no, how would I fix this?

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Try to learn the basics first

to learn ajax - http://www.w3schools.com/ajax
to learn html - http://www.w3schools.com/html/
to learn php - http://www.w3schools.com/php/
to learn jquery - http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/

Comment: like $("#date").text() + $("#time").text() in js to get data from <input type="text" id="date"> and <input type="text" id="time"> to use just in js function? Or posting to some php files so that u can use in php script?

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion by using jquery and ajax post method.

For example you have a form:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
 <input class="date" type="date" name="date">
 <button type="submit value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Jquery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // process the form
    $('form').submit(function(event) {

        // get the form data
        // there are many ways to get this data using jQuery (you can use the class or id also)
        var formData = {
            'date'              : $('input[name=date]').val()
        };

        // process the form
        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
            url         : 'process.php', // the url where we want to POST
            data        : formData, // our data object
            dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
            encode      : true
        })
            // using the done promise callback
            .done(function(data) {

                // log data to the console so we can see
                console.log(data); 

                // here we will handle errors and validation messages
            });

        // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
        event.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

there's a better way to do this. A easy and error free way. Use Angular JS. There are plenty of pre built codes for this kind of tasks. Have you done Angular ? And also you can use this datepicker.

http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Its a great and very customization one. And also you can use MVC structure as well.

Comment: I've never used Angular, recently started playing around with regular JS.
Is there some 'vanilla' way of getting the date and time from the HTML inputs to the JS script?